# Java. Linux. Multiple soundcards order

Tags: java, linux, audio

I wrote spring boot application for capturing audio from three the same soundcards, converting sound to mp3 and stream it to network.

Code for getting available devices:

```
public static Map<Integer, Mixer.Info> getAvailableDevices() {

    Mixer.Info[] mixers = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    Map<Integer, Mixer.Info> devices = new HashMap<>();
    for (Mixer.Info mixer : mixers) {
        Integer patternStart = mixer.getName().indexOf(ALSA_DEVICE_PATTERN);
        if (patternStart > 0) {
            devices.put(Integer.parseInt(mixer.getName().substring(patternStart + 4, patternStart + 5)), mixer);
        }
    }

    return devices;
}
```

My application started like linux demon after reboot. Also I need to restart capture when computer was rebooted. And there is a trouble. In linux soundcards get random order when computer is booting.

Way #1: Hard binding soundcards by serial number or else. But Mixer.Info don't contains information about serial number or anything else for hard binding. All devices have the same info.

Way #2: Hard binding soundcards in /etc/modprode.d/alsa-base for having the same cards order in system ever. But soundcards have the same kernel module also. Something like this:

```
options snd_ca0106 index=0
options snd_ca0106 index=1
options snd_ca0106 index=2
```

I can't guarantee that there will be the same order of devices after the reboot.

I don't know how I can do it. Help me, please.

Comment: google turned up this.. http://alsa.opensrc.org/MultipleCards section 6 (the anchor link doesnt seem to work so you'll have to scroll down)

Comment: Oh, thanks. This is a good decision.

Comment: snd-ca0106 module doesn't have vid and pid. So I can use udev rules. But I don't know how.